# React Router: What is the purpose of using <Outlet /> alone without context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

For what I understand now, if we pass an `Outlet` with context, the props after the context could be passed into child, and outlet act as a template that pass those props into any child the router may render.

My question is, what if we just set `<Outlet />` without context? If it doesn't pass any props, is there any reason why we particularly want to use `<Outlet />` alone?

Code may look like this

index.js

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Reset />
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Header cartItems={cartItems} />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Outlet` component alone allows nested routes to render their `element` content out and anything else the layout route is rendering, i.e. navbars, sidebars, specific layout components, etc.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
    <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

The `Checkout` component is rendered on `"/checkout"`. The `Reset`, `GlobalStyle`, and `Header` components are all also rendered as part of the layout route `"/"` rendering `App`. I.E. something like the following is rendered to the DOM.

```
...
<Reset />
<Header cartItems={cartItems} />
<Checkout />
...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.  Got it! So using <Outlet /> alone still do the trick of rendering other component to Checkout but doesn't pass any props.

Comment: @TaiwanNo.1 The only prop the `Outlet` component has is a `context` prop that is provided out in a React context and accessible only via the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#useoutletcontext) hook. It doesn't handle or pass around any other props to any other components if that's what you're asking about. Basically the main purpose is to allow sharing of common logic/UI in a layout route.

Comment: I see! I've tried out using Outlet alone and the router still works.  Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 6):

This is the mental model I used to grasp the concept of Outlet:

[image: Outlet]

Answer (score 0):

The  element is used as a placeholder. In this case an enables the Users component to render its child routes. Thus the element will render either a  or  element depending on the current location.

Answer (score 0):

the outlet element is just used to determine where child routes of parent routes should be displayed within the parent routes instead of a new page